# creating server which can be used in android applicaion

Tags: android, webserver

i am going to create an android carpool app, where users can register using the app in mobile and post carpool offers. and other user can search for offers using their mobile app only.
    so i want to create a server which can store the carpool offer and registration details, and also display the same when some other user searches for the offer.
     i dont know how to create this server, i have another PC which i can make as a server, but i dont know how app will send/receive data from this server... or if any other way i can create a server please guide.

Comment: I guess you could use [parse.com](https://www.parse.com/) instead of your own server & api. Never used it but it seems to be quite popular and it's free under certain conditions.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Search for "mcruiseon" they have the server part figured out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create *server* instead create a *web-app* or *web-service* app and request it via `Apache Http client API`. I'd like to suggest - [Jersey RESTful Web services.](http://jersey.java.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Basic equipment:

- tomcat apache (or any app server)
- mysql (or any db)
- java for creating a backend to manage data

You could create some web service (look for [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)) to manage the request for retrieving and for sending data using JSON ([gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a good and reliable lib)

Answer (score 0):

There is  lot of ways to create server for your android appplication - which is the best for you depends on what you got on server side.  In any case you will need own webserver on some domain under your control with possibility to create dynamic content.

Some assorted random thoughts:

Easiest way from android client point of view will be some REST HTTP based service, with possibility of user authentification.  You may consider using secure connection (just in case )

Authentification will be necessary.  Easiest way two implement would be some basic authentification for just your app, but it will be not very secure.  Reasonable security can be achieved with OAuth like authentification.

Best solution for you will be to use  some cloud hosting service  (like at amazon, gae, heroku or others). Most cloud hosting services will provide you with REST style frameworks out of the box,  integration with identity providers and some convenient database engine.

Do not be affraid of costs, as almost every cloud service will give you free account with some processing capacity and if you outgrow basic service you will probably have big enough user base to pay for this.

Comment: thanks for the reply, appreciated.